# Visual studio intellisense is not auto completing unity monobehaviour methods

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

I had visual studio 2019(don't know which version) and intellisense was working fine. It was suggesting every unity functions(like start, update, onTriggerEnter, etc.) as well as user defined functions.

Then there is info that Microsoft has removed its support for this version and i had to update it to 2019 v16.11.18. And now the intellisense which was previously working fine in every respect, stopped suggesting unity event functions or monobehaviour functions only. Other keywords like gameobject, transform, GetComponent or user defined functions are being suggested without any problem. Its just some  those crucial monobehaviour functions which got this problem.

I have double checked external tools settings in unity as well as tools for unity option in visual studio. My visual studio is not saying miscellaneous files on top left and i have nothing more to do.

Please help me..

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the project files?  Edit->Preferences->External Tools->[Regenerate project files]

Comment: Yes i have with one time ticking player projects option and then unticking it so as to give it a variation which, i thought, might reset the intellisense. But nothing works.

Comment: I have also tried visual studio 2022 around one month back but this problem was there too. So i switch back to vs2019 because it was taking too much ram. So in both versions this problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is fixed now. What i did is open visual studio installer and click repair on my visual studio. That's it.